# Does the Samsung wireless charger for the S6 have built-in surge protection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I waz speaking to Samsung rep and she says the S6 is safe to charge even with electricity fluctuations with the OEM wireless charger. Is there any fact to this? So is the wireless charger safer for the phone than using a wall charger with no external surge protection?

Comment: Posting as a comment since I'm not 100% sure and have no source to back it up, but I'm pretty skeptical of claims that your phone's charger actually has built-in surge protection. You should ask your rep how many joules it is rated for. If they can't answer, then it's probably not actually giving any protection.

Comment: @dotVezz So there is no other new tech in existence that could be protecting the phone either right?